# Removing elements within sublists

Tags: scheme

I have a list of the form:

```
((1 (3 2 4)) (2 (3 1)) (3 (2 1)) (4 (1)))
```

This list represents a graph of the form("node" ("edges")). How might I approach writing a procedure that takes a value representing an node, for example "1", and removes that node from the graph. For example: (delete-node n g) with input 5 and '((1 (3 2)) (2 (3 1)) (3 (2 1)) (4 (5)) (5 (4))) should output:

```
((1 (3 2)) (2 (3 1)) (3 (2 1)) (4 ()))
```

As can be observed from the example above, the node and any edges added to that node must both be removed. My code thus far is as follows:

```
(define graph '((1 (3 2)) (2 (3 1)) (3 (2 1)) (4 (5)) (5 (4))))

;...Other procedures not shown...

(define (delete-node n g)
    (define (delete ls item)
      (cond ((null? ls) nil)
            ((pair? (car ls))
             (cons (delete (car ls) item) (delete (cdr ls) item)))
            ((equal? (car ls) item) (delete (cdr ls) item))
            (else (cons (car ls) (delete (cdr ls) item)))))
      (delete (filter (lambda (x) (not (eq? (car x) n))) g) n))

(delete-node 5 graph)
```

The above code works, but is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Again, what have you tried? Could you post what you have so far so we can see where you're getting stuck?

Comment: Updated to clarify the problem and add more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible definition using high-level functions is the following:

```
(define (delete-node n g)
  (map (lambda(x) (list (car x) (filter (lambda(x) (not (= x n))) (cadr x))))
       (filter (lambda(x) (not (= (car x) n))) g)))

(delete-node 5 '((1 (3 2)) (2 (3 1)) (3 (2 1)) (4 (5)) (5 (4))))
       ; produces ((1 (3 2)) (2 (3 1)) (3 (2 1)) (4 ()))
```

A slightly more efficient solution with a recursive function is instead the following:

```
(define (delete-node n g)
  (cond ((null? g) '())
        ((= (caar g) n) (delete-node n (cdr g)))
        (else (cons (list (caar g) (filter (lambda(x) (not (= x n))) (cadar g)))
                    (delete-node n (cdr g))))))
```

If the graph is large and you know that its structure is correct, 
 knowing that only one outgoing arc from a node can be equal to `n`, a more efficient version could be the following:

```
(define (delete-node n g)
  (define (delete-edge edges)
    (cond ((null? edges) '())
          ((= (car edges) n) (cdr edges))  ; stop recursion when the edge is found
          (else (delete-edge (cdr edges)))))
  (cond ((null? g) '())
        ((= (caar g) n) (delete-node n (cdr g)))
        (else (if (member n (cadar g) =)
                  (cons (list (caar g) (delete-edge (cadar g)))
                        (delete-node n (cdr g)))
                  (cons (car g) (delete-node n (cdr g)))))))
```

Note that the test `(member n (cadar g) =)` is done to avoid copying the list of edges when `n` is not present.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether I understand your question correctly - does this match your needs?

```
(define (delete-node node graph)
  (define node-1 (car node))
  (define node-2 (cdr node))
  (let iter ((graph graph) (result '()))
    (if (null? graph)
        (reverse result)
        (let* ((head (car graph)) (head-1 (car head)) (head-2 (cadr head)))
          (iter (cdr graph)
                (cons (cond
                        ((eqv? head-1 node-1) (list head-1 (remove node-2 head-2)))
                        ((eqv? head-1 node-2) (list head-1 (remove node-1 head-2)))
                        (else         head))
                      result))))))
```

Testing:

```
> (delete-node '(2 . 3) '((1 (3 2 4)) (2 (3 1)) (3 (2 1)) (4 (1))))
'((1 (3 2 4)) (2 (1)) (3 (1)) (4 (1)))
> (delete-node '(1 . 2) '((1 (3 2 4)) (2 (3 1)) (3 (2 1)) (4 (1))))
'((1 (3 4)) (2 (3)) (3 (2 1)) (4 (1)))
```